# unable to insert json object inside another in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

```
UsersModel.findOne({"userName":userName}).exec(function (err, users) {
          if (err) {       
              logger.info("My Error "+err);
              return res.status(500).send(err);
          }
          else if(!users)
              return res.status(404).send('No user found');
          else {
              users["Account"]="XXXXXXXXX";

             return res.status(200).send(users);
          }
        });
```

I want to insert Account key pair value inside the users json.But the return users json does not contain account fields.Where is the issue ?

Comment: are you saying that `users.Account`  is null?

Comment: No the key pair in nothing showing in the return users json.The json contains only the structure receiving from mongoDB.

Comment: check any typo.. code looks fine...

Comment: Do you have a accounts-field in your schema? Documents returned by Mongoose are not JSON objects directly, you'll need to convert them to an object to add properties to them. something = something.toObject(); Of course, the easy way is to just add an account-field to your schema. (Even if you never save anything in it to the database.)

Comment: There is also [.lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean).  `UsersModel.findOne({"userName":userName}).lean().exec(...`

Comment: yes,lean() is working.